# Advanced Event Viewer filters

Tags: powershell

Exist the possibility to extract some information from Event viewer about event id description via powershell?
For example i want to see if I have on domain controller this event id 4776 with description "Authentication Package: WDigest".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Get-WinEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-winevent)'s `-FilterXPath` parameter to very granularly filter against the raw event xml.

In your case we could find all WDigest auth events with:

```bsh
Get-WinEvent -FilterXPath "*[System[EventID=4776] and EventData[Data[@Name='PackageName']='WDigest']]" -LogName "Security"
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tested your script and works fine. I think i have learned some new things about powershell

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier with the logname or providername, but it's possible to search all the logs, unlike in the event viewer.  You can't just say '*' for the logname, because of a 256 logname query limit in the windows api:

```
get-winevent -listlog * | 
foreach { 
  get-winevent @{ logname = $_.logname; id = 4776 } -ea 0 } | 
where message -match 'Authentication Package: WDigest'
```

In powershell 6 or 7 you can filter on named eventdata:

```
get-winevent @{ Logname = 'Security'; ID = 4776; PackageName = 'WDigest' }
```

In powershell 5 maybe this.  Data can't have wildcards.

```
get-winevent @{ Logname = 'Security'; ID = 4776; Data = 'WDigest' }
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback , your scripts works well and , we are use powershell 5 and i have work with the last one.

Comment: Hello , can be that script improved, for example i want to extract a all events with this ID 5829, but i have a lot of this kind of events. For example i have more events from one computer, exist the possibility to filter and export just for different computers which create this events. For example I have Machine SamAccountName: server123 the problem is that i have mare than 100 event from that computer

Comment: @bogdan09 You can have multiple event id's separated by commas, and use invoke-command for remote computers.  You should probably ask your own question with the code you've tried.